# Where in the Shiva Purana does Lord Shiva say " ekam prasamshati yastu sarvAneva prasamshati...."?

Tags: scripture, shiva, shiva-purana, shloka

Supposedly, in the Shiva Purana, Lord Shiva says to Goddess Parvati the following verse:

> Ekam prasamshati yastu sarvAneva prasamshati |
>  Ekam nindati yasteshAm
>   sarvAneva vinindati ||
>
> **Meaning**
>
> One who praises one, praises all and one who censures one thereby
>   censures all.

The context here is of condemning `Iswara Ninda` ( that is condemning the act of criticism of God).

I want to know where exactly in the Shiva Purana is this verse found.

If by chance it is not there in the Shiva Purana, then the follow up question is- Which scripture contains it?

Comment: i searched in Shiva Purana but couldn't find it.

Comment: Ok but my source says its in there, anyways lets see.. @TheDestroyer

Comment: @Rickross What is your source?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan The Shaktananda Tarangini. http://www.shivashakti.com/shaktanan.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These verses can be found in **[Chapter 3](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/1_sanskr/3_purana/brndp2_u.htm) Upodghatapada of Brahmanda Purana**
([translated](https://archive.org/stream/BrahmandaPurana_37/BrahmandaPurana-G.v.tagare-Part2#page/n27/mode/2up) by GV Tagore).

> कारणं तु स्मृता ह्येते नानार्थेष्विह देवताः | 
>  एकं प्रशंसमानस्तु
> सर्वानेवप्रशसति || ९३
>
> kāraṇaṃ tu smṛtā hyete nānārtheṣviha devatāḥ | 
> ekaṃ praśaṃsamānastu
> sarvānevapraśasati || 93
>
> 93.These deities are remembered as the cause of the  different affairs. A person who praises one, praises all.
>
> एकं निन्दति यस्त्वेषां सर्वानेव स निन्दति | 
>  न प्रद्वेषस्ततः कार्यो
> देवतासु विजानता || ९४
>
> ekaṃ nindati yastveṣāṃ sarvāneva sa nindati | 
> na pradveṣastataḥ kāryo
> devatāsu vijānatā || 94
>
> 94.He who censures one censures all. Hence, no one  who knows these, should have hatred towards the deities.

Reverse order of verses can be found in **[Chapter 66](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/vayu-mahapurana/text-with-translation/vol-ii/chapter-66/topic-2) of Vayu Purana**. (translated by Sudharshan Kumar Sharma)

> एकं निन्दति यस्तेषां सर्वानेव स निन्दति। 
>  एकं प्रशंसमानस्तु
> सर्वानेव प्रशंसति। 
>  एकं यो वेत्ति पुरुषं तमाहुर्ब्रह्मवादिनम्।।
> ११४।।
>
> ekaṃ nindati yasteṣāṃ sarvāneva sa nindati। 
>  ekaṃ praśaṃsamānastu
> sarvāneva praśaṃsati। 
>  ekaṃ yo vetti puruṣaṃ
> tamāhurbrahmavādinam।। 114।।
>
> He who censures one among them censures all. He who eulogises one,
> eulogises all of them. They declare him as Brahmavadin (propounder of
> Brahman) who understands one Purusa.

But in both cases speaker of those verses is **Suta** not Lord Shiva and Suta explains "Race of Dharma" in those chapters.